# NeoVim: Move the cursor after running a command in :terminal

Tags: neovim

I have function to perform a git diff, after calling git diff I wish to emulate the following keypresses in the terminal window:

- `G` move to the end of the file
- `a` append
- `q<cr>` type q to quit the "terminal scrolling mode" then enter
- `gg` return to the top of the file

Code:

```
function GitDiff()
  terminal git diff --word-diff %
  normal Gaq<Esc>gg
endfunction
:nmap <leader>t :call GitDiff()<cr>
```

However the keypresses dont seem to be executed as expected. I wonder if it needs a delay to wait for the terminal command to finish executing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
function GitDiff()
    terminal git diff --word-diff %
    call feedkeys("Gag\<Esc>gg")
endfunction
nmap <leader>t :call GitDiff()<cr>
```

I replaced `normal Gaq<Esc>gg` for a call to feedkeys().

`:h feedkeys`